# How to change css frequently by jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div having some text which is frequently changed by jquery. So the height of the div is changed frequently. So I have to change a div height frequently. My code:

```
function adjust_height() {
    var h = $('.user-feedback').height() + 20+'px';
    $('.certificate').css("height",h);
}

var settings = ({
    timeout: 20000,
    animation_duration: 2000
})

$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(addRotator, settings.timeout);
    function addRotator() {
        adjust_height();
        var currentFeedback = $(".user-feedback div.current");
        var nextFeedback = currentFeedback.next().length ? currentFeedback.next() : $(".user-feedback div:first");
        currentFeedback.removeClass("current").addClass("previous");
        nextFeedback.addClass("current");
        $('.previous').hide(100);
        $('.current').show(1000);

    }
});//
```

Here adjust_height() function update the height. But height is being set first time and it is not being updated. Any suggestion.

Comment: your functions seem to be working fine. Is it possible that you have given a fixed height to `.user-feedback`, so that the height you calculate for `.certificate` is always the same. That's why you only notice the height first time, as after that it keeps updated to the same value?

Comment: Are you sure addRotator function is being called in the interval? Did you put a breakpoint in the function to test this?